# Sitecore :: Unable to implement redirection request for png, jpg formats

Tags: c#, sitecore, redirect

I have the following redirection requirement:

From URL: http://localsource.com/images/products/example.jpg

To URL:localsource.com/some-landing page

I have heard from some expert we need to update web.config file adding extensions like jpg, png, .air for resolving above kind of redirections requests.
I am confused here, Can anyone help here please with the exact answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and add code below to your `web.config` file:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite jpg">
      <match url="^images/products/example.jpg" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="some-landing page" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

For more information, check [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)  article.